# select correct redis database on reconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I have a node application that uses node_redis. Upon application start, a redis client is created, the correct database is selected once, and then this client is used for every request:

```
this.redis = redis.createClient(port, host);
this.redis.on('error', function(err) { console.log('Redis error: ' + err); });
this.redis.send_command('SELECT', [database]);
```

Now the problem is: when the connection goes away (for example when redis is manually restarted), node_redis automatically re-connects, but it's on the wrong database, since the `SELECT`was not run after re-connecting. I cannot find how to detect this, since the error event also doesn't fire in this case. What should I do?

Comment: Did you try `this.redis.select(db, function() {..})`?

Comment: @RahilWazir: this would generally be a good idea to make sure no request is sent before the SELECT is executed. However, the above code is only run upon initialization. But when the connection goes away, node_redis reconnects by itself and then the SELECT is not run at all

Comment: I thought that the `connect` event could be used to trigger the `select`. But then I would need a separate mechanism to queue requests until the `select` is finished, and I wonder if there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: Hmm yeah I don't think its possible within `node_redis`, you can look at NodeBB [`loader.js`](https://github.com/NodeBB/NodeBB/blob/master/loader.js#L149) which uses node cluster module to re spinning the process. You can add workers and listen for events.